# How to host a website to the sever and how to get database accesibility?

Tags: html, database, forms, validation, alert

I want get database access and put my website into server

I want solution for the question how to host website to the server

I want to know how the data is stored in database and how it is verified and give results

Answer (score 0):

You must purchase local host servers from providers like as Bigrock, Godaddy, and others, and the database is hosted in their portal, which you may access.there are so many youtube videos you can just refer it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps involved in hosting a website on a server and giving it access to a database:

Choose a hosting provider: First, you'll need to choose a hosting provider that offers the type of hosting you need (such as shared hosting, VPS hosting, or dedicated hosting). The hosting provider will provide you with server space, a domain name, and other necessary tools for hosting your website.

Set up a database: Your hosting provider will usually offer a variety of database options, such as MySQL or PostgreSQL. You'll need to choose a database and set it up on the server. This will usually involve creating a database user and password, as well as setting up tables and fields to store your data.

Upload your website files: Once you have a domain name and a place to host your website, you'll need to upload your website files to the server. You can do this using a variety of tools, such as FTP (File Transfer Protocol) or a content management system (CMS) like WordPress.

Connect your website to the database: In order for your website to access the database, you'll need to configure it to connect to the database using the appropriate credentials (such as the database hostname, username, and password). This will usually involve editing your website's configuration files or using a CMS plugin.

Test and launch your website: Once your website is set up and connected to the database, you should test it to make sure everything is working correctly. Once you're satisfied with the results, you can launch your website and make it available to the public.

Answer (score 0):

First You have to write an application that can connect to databases you can pick any language like Python, Java, Ruby on Rails etc, and you can chose any database Relational/Non-Relational like (Postgres SQL, MySQL, MongoDB).

then you can buy Virtual Machine Server on `Digital Ocean` or `AWS` and then you have to deploy the application to the server.

and then you can add SSL and point your server to your own domain which you can buy from NameCheap, Godaddy or from any other platform of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

To host your site to server, you need to

1. Register your domain
2. Choose hosting provider. It depends on your requirement. If you develop your site using PHP and MySQL, then you can find Linux provider. If you are using .NET and MSSQL database, it will better for you use Windows hosting. There are many providers that you can use, like Asphostportal, TMD, WP Engine, etc. I personally use Asphostportal to host my Asp net website.
3. Once you have registered hosting and domain name, please just kindly upload all your files using FTP to your root folder. You can also use File Manager to upload your files.

Good luck!